# Boolean Difference misbehaviour

Tags: edit-mode

This appears to be a perennial problem. None of the solutions I've read here so far work when I try them on this very simple geometry.

I am trying to perform a Boolean Difference on Cube.001 using Cube.002

Whenever I attempt it, Cube.001 simply disappears.

I have checked for duplicate vertices, manifold geometry, and interior faces. I have set all normals outside.

What is it that I'm overlooking?

[image: Problem geometry]

The .blend file is here: [sdkfz3_15mm.blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33836019/sdkfz3_15mm.blend)

[image]

Comment: Working fine on my end, You problem is probably overlapping faces. Boolean operations don't like coplanar or coinciding faces. Check the base of the objects on the bottom, make sure they are not overlapping, give them some offset distance

Comment: Both objects have all their surfaces offset.

Comment: Their bottom faces are overlapping

Comment: They are overlapping (otherwise there would be no Difference possible) but they are not coplanar — I think you are looking at the wrong two objects. Cube.001 is the highlighted object, Cube.002 is the left-most object with the bevelled corner. Their bottom faces are offset by about 3mm.

Comment: I eventually got the Difference operation to work by triangulating both objects, performing the Boolean operation, and then doing a Limited Dissolve on Cube.001 to return it to quads.

I don't know precisely why that would work, unless maybe one or other object had one or more non-planar faces — but I would have thought that would have been shown by the check for manifold geometry.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, you really should report it [here](http://developer.blender.org/).

Comment: My bad, you are right, I was looking at the wrong objects, indeed it may be a bug. Somehow blender was unable to preform the operation, but subdividing the mesh or adding a loop vertically in the middle of to Cube.02 seems to work around the problem